# Laravel Validation against Unique Values

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I would like to create a validation for the update function
I would like it to exclude the title for that dedant id

```html
  public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
      $this->validate($request,[
         'title' => "required|unique:posts,title,".$id.'id',
         'image' => 'image',
         'categories' => 'required',
         //'tags' => 'required',
         'body' => 'required',
     ]);
```

Comment: Remove the 'id' string at the end. Try this:

'title' => "required|unique:posts,title,".$id,

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This code will work,

```
 public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
        {
          $this->validate($request,[
             'title' => ["required,unique:posts,title,".$this->route('post')],
             'image' => 'image',
             'categories' => 'required',
             //'tags' => 'required',
             'body' => 'required',
         ]);
```

Let me know is it work for you.

Comment: 'title' => ["required, unique:posts, title,".$this->route('post')] 
okay use this code

Comment: thanks I resolve in this mode : 'title' => "required|unique:posts,title,".$post->id.'id',

Answer (score 0):

I propose another example that works maybe it can come in handy

```html
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $this->validate($request,[
  'name' => "required|unique:categories,name,".$id.'id',
  'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
    $rules = [
              'title' => 'required|unique:posts,title,'.$id,
              'image' => 'image',
              'categories' => 'required',
              'body' => 'required',
            ];
    $this->ValidateForm($request->all(), $rules);
    $post= Post::find($id);  
    if($post){
       $post->title  = $request->title;
       $post->categories  = $request->categories;
       $post->body  = $request->body;
       if ($request->hasFile('image')){
             Storage::delete($request->profile_photo);
             $post->image = $request->file('image')->store('post');
       }
      $post->save();
    }
 }
```